# on existence of supremum/infimum

Tags: elementary-set-theory, probability-distributions, compactness

It is known that minimum or maximum of a function does not always exist but the supremum/infimum usually tends to exist.

**Example 1:**
For example, if we consider $X$ as the set or rational numbers with $a_n\in X$ and consider the sequence

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{2}+\frac{1}{a_n}$$

this sequence tends to $\sqrt{2}$ which is not rational but a real number. This means that rational numbers are not compact and supremum or infimum is possible not to be achieved in the rational numbers. However such supremum or infimum can be achieved in the real numbers. For example

$$\{a\mbox{ rational}:a^2<2\}$$

and the supremum is $\sqrt{2}$.

**Example 2:**
Similarly on real numbers $X=\mathbb{R}$

$$\arg\sup 1-e^{-x}$$

doesnt exist but if one extends the real number set to extended real number set then $$\arg\sup 1-e^{-x}=\infty$$.

**Question:**
Let us consider the closed ball

$$
X=\{g:D(g,f)\leq \epsilon\}
$$
of density functions, i.e. $f$ and $g$ are probability density functions, e.g. on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon$ is a small positive number. Here $D$ is some distance for example KL-divergece.

This closed ball is defined on an infinite dimensional space and closed balls on infinite dimensional spaces are not compact. This suggests that supremum and infimum do not necessarily exist in the space.

Here I am trying the make an analogy with the two examples above and try to find the supremum ouside of $X$, namely on some $Y\supset X$. At this point I am confused because the ball is not open, it is closed and something outside this closed ball will not satisfy the condition $D(g,f)\leq \epsilon$.

**Regarding Noah's answer:** of course there is a functional of density functions and supremum is searched over this functional. For example:
        $$T=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\delta g \mathrm{d}\mu\quad\mbox{for some}\,\,\delta$$

> Is there any common notation kind of $Y=$**extended closed ball** such that all supremums/infimums exist in this space? Here I am talking about the argument, namely a density function which provides the supremem like in the second example, where it was provided by $\infty$.
>
> Would the extension with the set $Y=\{g:D(g,f)\leq \epsilon^{'}\}$ with $\epsilon^{'}>\epsilon$ guarantee the existence of supremums/infimums defined on $X$?
>
> Is there any case where $Y$ needs to extend to include non-density functions for the existence of supremums/infimums?

Comment: In Example 2 the sup does exist and is the real number 1. (It's the max that doesn't exist.)

Comment: @coffeemath sorry that was about the argument.

Comment: If in Example 2 the domain is the reals then the argument of any real $a$  is 0 ($a>0$) or $\pi$ ($a<0$ or undefined when $a=0..$ Note I don't get why a downvote was given. Actually only when considering the reals as a subset of the complexes does the notion of argument come in.

Comment: @coffeemath what does $a$ have something to do with example 2?

Comment: The usual lim sup of $1-e^{-x}$ as $x \to \infty$ is the real number $1$ whose argument as a complex number is $0$. On the other hand if $x \to -\infty$ the lim sup is still $1$ but there is then no lim inf since it goes to $- \infty$ as $x \to -\infty.$ In that example you did specify the domain was all reals but didn't say lim sup of which, or maybe you meant to look at the entire range of the function, which is the whole set of reals...

Comment: @coffeemath yes I meant that..thx for the information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33246/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-seyhmus-gungoren).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a step back, to more generality: you're asking what we can conclude about the existence of suprema/infima (and maxima/minima) of a functional defined on some subset of a metric space.

- First of all, if the functional in question isn't continuous, then there's basically nothing that can be said.
- Assuming we restrict attention to continuous functionals $H: A\subseteq X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then we have the following easy results:

  - If $A$ is compact, then $\max(H(A))$ exists. (Ditto for $\inf$.)
  - If $A$ is contained in some compact set $B\subseteq A$, then $\sup(H(A))$ exists. (Ditto for $\sup$.)
  - These assumptions are necessary. For instance, consider $X=\mathbb{R}, H=id, A=(0, 1)$. Then $\sup(H(A))$ and $\inf(H(A))$ exist, but $\max(H(A))$ and $\min(H(A))$ do not. Meanwhile, if we take $X$ to be Baire space with its usual metric, then given any nonempty open subset $A$ of $X$ there is a continuous surjection from $A$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
- Meanwhile, if our target space is $\mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty,-\infty\}$, then suprema/infima always exist, regardless of what $X, A, H$ are.

---

Re: your most recent comment: there, we were extending the *codomain*. If we make the codomain compact - that is, pass from values-in-$\mathbb{R}$ to values-in-the-extended-reals - then *every* functional has a supremum, continuous or no, from a compact set or no.

But you're asking about expanding the *domain* a little. This in general isn't possible: if I have a subset $A\subseteq X$ of a complete metric space, which is not contained in any compact subset of $X$, then I may very well have a continuous surjection from $A$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Such a surejection obviously has no supremum (unless I expand the codomain).

This domain/codomain issue, by the way, was why I misunderstood your question at first.

Comment: I added some more to the question reagarding your answers first paragaph.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören I'm sorry, but that still doesn't really address my point. Are you asking about the supremum of a subset of a metric space (or topological space, or etc.)? In that case, that's not even a meaningful notion if the space is not ordered. Are you asking about the supremum of *a functional defined on* a subset of a space? In that case, what is the codomain of your functional? If the codomain is ordered, then that question makes sense, but otherwise we're back to the above.

Comment: Elaborating on the functional version: if I ask "Does $\sup \{f(x): x\in A\}$ exist?" for some subset $A\subseteq X$ and function $f: X\rightarrow Y$, where $Y$ is ordered, then this question makes sense: $B:=\{f(x): x\in A\}$ is a subset of $Y$, and I'm asking whether $B$ has a supremum. Note, though, that this isn't really a question about the $X$-side of things anymore: if $Y=[0, 1]$, then the answer will be yes, regardless of what $X$, $A$, and $f$ are (okay fine, as long as $A\not=\emptyset$ :P).

Comment: I dont get what you mean. If the space of functions are given by $X$ as in the question and if we are interested in the existence of a density function $g^*$ (f is known and given) on $X$ such that the supremum of $T$ is achieved for this $g^*$. Will I be able to guarantee the existence of such $g^*$ all the time (for any $\delta$ or even $T$). I think it is not possible. Then where should I look for such a $g^*$. I understood that supremum is more related to the completeness than it is related to the compactness. But how does it help me here?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören I **still** do not understand what you are asking for: the supremum *of what* is achieved for this $g$? Are you asking for the supremum of *the set* $\{g: d(f, g)\le\epsilon\}$? Then that question does not even make sense, since the space of functions isn't ordered. Or are you asking for the supremum of *some functional defined on* $\{g: d(f, g)\le \epsilon\}$? If so, *what* functional? These are different questions. The first part of your question suggests the former, but the second suggests the latter.

Comment: If it's the latter, by the way, then compactness *does* come back into play: if $H$ is a continuous functional from $A$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and $A$ is compact, then $H(A)$ will have a maximum. If $A$ is contained in a compact set, then $H(A)$ will be bounded, and so will have a supremum. If $A$ is not contained in a compact set, then all bets are off.

Comment: i do not ask the supremum of a set. I ask the supremum of a functional defined over this set. Analogy is the function given which was defined over real numbers. Now instead of real numbers as the domain, we have the set of density functions. Let $T$ a convex functional of $g$.

Comment: $X$ is not compact. what I can do is to increase the radius of the closed ball. Then it will include many other density functions. Will this help me to achive the supremum of $T$, where $T$ is a convex functional of $g$? if not what can I do? in real numbers I extend the domain(exampe 2 in the question) and I am done.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Expanding the domain won't necessarily help at all; see my edit.

Comment: okay I think I should have added the functional $T$ while I was writing the question. Sorry for that.

Comment: one last thing. If I know that $T\in[0,1]$ for every $g$ and $T$ is a convex functional of $g$ as in the question. Would this be of any help?

Comment: Well, then, since the codomain is compact, $T(A)$ has a supremum for *any* nonempty set $A$. On the other hand, if $A$ is very non-compact, I don't see a reason for this supremum to be achieved anywhere near $A$ - and all convexity says here (that I can see) is that the sup of the functional on a closed ball is equal to the sup of the functional on the *boundary* of that ball. But again, I don't see why that has to be achieved anywhere near $A$.

Comment: thank you very much for the clarifications. This is exactly how I was thinking;)